# Adding Attribute to XML Node from Class Structure VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am producing XML from VB.NET and asmx

I define a structure, then populate it in my code, this is then returned via XML to a user.  Is there a way I can put attributes on a node?

```
Structure Output
Dim First as string
Dim Second as string
End Structure

 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function ProduceOutput(byval Test as string) as Output
Dim output as new Output
output.First="Hello"
output.Second="World"

ProduceOutput=output

End Function
```

This produces

```
<Output>
<First>Hello</First>
<Second>World</Second>
</Output>
```

How can I produce

```
<Output>
    <First this="##valueoftest##">Hello</First>
    <Second>World</Second>
    </Output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create own class for `First` property. Define `XmlAttribute` for property which you want use as attribute.
`XmlText` will be serialized as value of parent element

```vb
<XmlType>
Public Class FirstType

   <XmlAttribute> 
   Public Property This As String

   <XmlText> 
   Public Property Value As String

End Class
```

Then change `Output.First` to type of that Class

```vb
Public Class Output
    Public Property First As FirstType
End Class
```

Result:

```xml
<Output>
    <First This="ThisValue">FirstValue</First>
    <Second>SecondValue</Second>
</Output>
```

Same logic works for `Structure` too